# MYSQL Subqueries with join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Im trying to select values through a table only containing references to other tables in mysql.
The reference table contains only INTs **userId, answer1, answer2, date**.

They are refering to a user table and an answer table. The answer table has three columns: **id, answer, difficulty**.

The problem im having is with selecting two values from the same column in the same query. Heres what ive got so far

```
SELECT
    nickname, 
    (SELECT answer FROM feed LEFT JOIN answerTable a ON answer1 = s.id) AS first,
    (SELECT answer FROM feed LEFT JOIN answerTable a ON answer2 = s.id) AS second,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i:%S %e-%c-%Y') AS date
FROM feed
LEFT JOIN users ON user = id;
```

With this query i get multiple values in the subqueries.

Ive tried for a while now and need some fresh eyes on this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT
    nickname, 
    a1.answer AS a_first,
    a2.answer AS a_second,  
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i:%S %e-%c-%Y') AS date
FROM 
    feed
    LEFT JOIN users ON feed.userId = users.id
    LEFT JOIN answerTable a1 ON feed.answer1 = a1.id
    LEFT JOIN answerTable a2 ON feed.answer2 = a2.id;
```

If I understood well, you need to connect to id's from table `feed` the detailed information about users from `users` table and for each of the answers pulling it from `answers` table. So besides the `left join` to `users` that you already did there are 2 additional joins on each of the answer id's - it results in searching answers table separately for answer1 and answer2.

I hope it might help you some way.

Comment: I'm glad then I could help . Regards.